# java : Not able to save in list at specified index

Tags: java, list

I am trying to add objects to List using `java.util.List.add(int location, Object object)`

When I add the first Object, it gets stored in the location as shown in below screen shot (Not sure why the index is 9 though I wanted it to store at index 0)

Below is my code

```
InstructionCRUDTO instructionCRUDTO = new InstructionCRUDTO();
    List<InstructionCRUDTO> instructionCRUDTOListCRDB = new ArrayList<InstructionCRUDTO>();
    int instructionCount = 0;
    for(InstructionTemplate instruction : recurringInstructionGroup.getInstructions())
    {   
        instructionCRUDTO.setExecutionDate(Long.valueOf(instruction.getDetails().getExecutionDate().getTime()));

        instructionCRUDTOListCRDB.add(instructionCount,instructionCRUDTO);
        instructionCount++;
    }
```

[image: AddToFirstIndex]

When I add 2nd object to the list, the first object is getting overwritten by the 2nd object.
My problem is, I am not able to store the initially added objects in the list. The last inserted object is overwriting the already added objects. Please refer below screen shot.

I just wanted to use `java.util.List.add(Object)` instead of `List.add(inst Location, Object object)` but its not working as well.

[image: LastInsertion]

Comment: Please show your code

Comment: Yes, debugging invisible code is rough.

Comment: Seems as location is always the same. Let's confirm with the code

Comment: I have posted my code...

Comment: " but its not working as well." How is using add not working?

Comment: @EvanKnowles Evan, if I use add I am facing the same problem of last added object overriding the initially added objects. The problem with `add` is same as the problem I am facing with `add(location, object)`

Comment: Please post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org). As a starting point, I have converted your code fragment to a running example, but it does **not** reproduce your issue: http://ideone.com/DWuXKL (also the debugger shows the expected values)

Answer (score 0):

There's only one `InstructionCRUDTO` instance, it's always the same (created outside the loop).. 
So every `add` you make on the list add the same object at a different index.

Move `InstructionCRUDTO instructionCRUDTO = new InstructionCRUDTO();` inside the for-loop to fix the *"issue"*

Comment: that does not explain the weird index behaviour. You **can** add the same object to a List multiple times at different indexes.

Comment: yes it does, see the comments "if I use add I am facing the same problem of last added object overriding the initially added objects"

Comment: Right, that might be a misunderstanding of OP that the object does not "override" the first one, but simply being added again after the previous one ... Still, the first issue still is that OP mentions that the first object is added at index `[9]`, which is, IMHO, not possible with the code fragment from the question

Comment: My answer doesn't explain the `9`, I agree. And I agree with you on "impossible" with code shown.